# How to load a directed graphML file in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

I have used nw:load-graphml "filename.graphml" to load a directed graph in NetLogo, but it is loading undirected graph. Is there any other command to load a directed graphml file in NetLogo?

Below is the code, which I have used to load GraphML file. I have tried both the load-graph and load-graph1 procedures given below.

I also have added directed = "true" attribute to links in the graphml file, for example: 
      edge directed="true" id="2" source="14341" target="8312"
However, still network loaded is undirected.

```
    to load-graph
      let filename user-file
      if (filename != false) [
        nw:load-graphml filename [
          set shape "circle"
          set size 1
        ]
        nw:set-context turtles links
      ]
    end

    to load-graph1
      nw:load-graphml "myfile.graphml"
    end
```

GraphML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns">
    <key attr.name="label" attr.type="string" for="node" id="label"/>
    <key attr.name="Edge Label" attr.type="string" for="edge" id="edgelabel"/>
    <key attr.name="weight" attr.type="double" for="edge" id="weight"/>
    <key attr.name="r" attr.type="int" for="node" id="r"/>
    <key attr.name="g" attr.type="int" for="node" id="g"/>
    <key attr.name="b" attr.type="int" for="node" id="b"/>
    <key attr.name="x" attr.type="float" for="node" id="x"/>
    <key attr.name="y" attr.type="float" for="node" id="y"/>
    <key attr.name="size" attr.type="float" for="node" id="size"/>
    <graph edgedefault="directed">
    <node id="16">
    <data key="label">v16</data>
    <data key="size">100.0</data>
    <data key="r">0</data>
    <data key="g">0</data>
    <data key="b">0</data>
    <data key="x">4.917384E-7</data>
    <data key="y">48.0</data>
    </node>
    <node id="15">
    <data key="label">v15</data>
    <data key="size">97.648</data>
    <data key="r">0</data>
    <data key="g">0</data>
    <data key="b">0</data>
    <data key="x">14.832003</data>
    <data key="y">45.648003</data>
    </node>
    <node id="17">
    <data key="label">v17</data>
    <data key="size">97.648</data>
    <data key="r">0</data>
    <data key="g">0</data>
    <data key="b">0</data>
    <data key="x">-14.832001</data>
    <data key="y">45.648003</data>
    </node>
    <node id="14">
    <data key="label">v14</data>
    <data key="size">90.832</data>
    <data key="r">0</data>
    <data key="g">0</data>
    <data key="b">0</data>
    <data key="x">28.211998</data>
    <data key="y">38.832</data>
    </node>
    <node id="18">
    <data key="label">v18</data>
    <data key="size">90.832</data>
    <data key="r">0</data>
    <data key="g">0</data>
    <data key="b">0</data>
    <data key="x">-28.212002</data>
    <data key="y">38.832</data>
    </node>
    <node id="13">
    <data key="label">v13</data>
    <data key="size">80.212</data>
    <data key="r">0</data>
    <data key="g">0</data>
    <data key="b">0</data>
    <data key="x">38.832</data>
    <data key="y">28.211998</data>
    </node>
    <node id="19">
    <data key="label">v19</data>
    <data key="size">80.212</data>
    <data key="r">0</data>
    <data key="g">0</data>
    <data key="b">0</data>
    <data key="x">-38.832</data>
    <data key="y">28.211998</data>
    </node>
    <node id="12">
    <data key="label">v12</data>
    <data key="size">66.832</data>
    <data key="r">0</data>
    <data key="g">0</data>
    <data key="b">0</data>
    <data key="x">45.648003</data>
    <data key="y">14.832003</data>
    </node>
    <node id="20">
    <data key="label">v20</data>
    <data key="size">66.832</data>
    <data key="r">0</data>
    <data key="g">0</data>
    <data key="b">0</data>
    <data key="x">-45.648003</data>
    <data key="y">14.832003</data>
    </node>
    <node id="1">
    <data key="label">v1</data>
    <data key="size">52.000004</data>
    <data key="r">0</data>
    <data key="g">0</data>
    <data key="b">0</data>
    <data key="x">-48.000004</data>
    <data key="y">4.917384E-7</data>
    </node>
    <node id="11">
    <data key="label">v11</data>
    <data key="size">52.000004</data>
    <data key="r">0</data>
    <data key="g">0</data>
    <data key="b">0</data>
    <data key="x">48.0</data>
    <data key="y">4.917384E-7</data>
    </node>
    <node id="2">
    <data key="label">v2</data>
    <data key="size">37.168003</data>
    <data key="r">0</data>
    <data key="g">0</data>
    <data key="b">0</data>
    <data key="x">-45.648003</data>
    <data key="y">-14.832001</data>
    </node>
    <node id="10">
    <data key="label">v10</data>
    <data key="size">37.168003</data>
    <data key="r">0</data>
    <data key="g">0</data>
    <data key="b">0</data>
    <data key="x">45.648003</data>
    <data key="y">-14.832001</data>
    </node>
    <node id="3">
    <data key="label">v3</data>
    <data key="size">23.788002</data>
    <data key="r">0</data>
    <data key="g">0</data>
    <data key="b">0</data>
    <data key="x">-38.832</data>
    <data key="y">-28.212002</data>
    </node>
    <node id="9">
    <data key="label">v9</data>
    <data key="size">23.788002</data>
    <data key="r">0</data>
    <data key="g">0</data>
    <data key="b">0</data>
    <data key="x">38.832</data>
    <data key="y">-28.212002</data>
    </node>
    <node id="4">
    <data key="label">v4</data>
    <data key="size">13.168001</data>
    <data key="r">0</data>
    <data key="g">0</data>
    <data key="b">0</data>
    <data key="x">-28.212002</data>
    <data key="y">-38.832</data>
    </node>
    <node id="8">
    <data key="label">v8</data>
    <data key="size">13.168001</data>
    <data key="r">0</data>
    <data key="g">0</data>
    <data key="b">0</data>
    <data key="x">28.211998</data>
    <data key="y">-38.832</data>
    </node>
    <node id="5">
    <data key="label">v5</data>
    <data key="size">6.3519998</data>
    <data key="r">0</data>
    <data key="g">0</data>
    <data key="b">0</data>
    <data key="x">-14.832001</data>
    <data key="y">-45.648003</data>
    </node>
    <node id="7">
    <data key="label">v7</data>
    <data key="size">6.3519998</data>
    <data key="r">0</data>
    <data key="g">0</data>
    <data key="b">0</data>
    <data key="x">14.832003</data>
    <data key="y">-45.648003</data>
    </node>
    <node id="6">
    <data key="label">v6</data>
    <data key="size">4.0</data>
    <data key="r">0</data>
    <data key="g">0</data>
    <data key="b">0</data>
    <data key="x">4.917384E-7</data>
    <data key="y">-48.000004</data>
    </node>
    <edge id="0" source="20" target="9">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="1" source="17" target="8">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="2" source="18" target="2">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="3" source="7" target="11">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="4" source="16" target="4">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="5" source="12" target="9">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="6" source="5" target="16">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="7" source="9" target="1">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="8" source="10" target="4">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="9" source="2" target="1">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="10" source="18" target="15">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="11" source="4" target="11">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="12" source="4" target="2">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="13" source="9" target="8">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="14" source="6" target="8">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="15" source="4" target="1">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="16" source="2" target="18">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="17" source="19" target="6">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="18" source="1" target="6">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="19" source="8" target="9">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="20" source="10" target="3">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="21" source="12" target="19">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="22" source="11" target="4">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="23" source="3" target="18">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="24" source="13" target="14">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="25" source="10" target="2">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="26" source="17" target="6">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="27" source="6" target="7">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="28" source="12" target="16">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="29" source="20" target="3">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="30" source="13" target="5">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="31" source="20" target="11">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="32" source="11" target="15">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="33" source="20" target="15">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="34" source="15" target="17">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="35" source="10" target="8">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="36" source="14" target="7">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="37" source="8" target="2">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="38" source="16" target="7">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="39" source="1" target="19">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="40" source="5" target="13">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="41" source="1" target="20">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="42" source="17" target="4">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="43" source="13" target="9">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="44" source="14" target="12">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="45" source="8" target="13">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="46" source="8" target="1">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="47" source="9" target="2">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="48" source="5" target="14">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="49" source="16" target="11">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="50" source="4" target="9">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="51" source="1" target="8">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="52" source="7" target="12">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="53" source="20" target="16">
    <data key="weight">1.0</data>
    </edge>
    </graph>
    </graphml>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nw:load-graphml` *can* load directed graphs.

Make sure the `edgedefault="directed"` is set for the `<graph>` element in your GraphML file. Also make sure that, if you use a link breed, that breed is defined as directed inside NetLogo.

If that still doesn't work, you will have to show us a sample GraphML file and the exact code you use to load it...

**Edit**

I have investigated further, and I think this *might* be a bug in the way `nw` loads a GraphML file with unbreeded links.

The elegant way to get around it would be to create a breed of directed links and use a `breed` attribute inside your GraphML file to set the links' breed.

A much quicker, more hackish way to get around the problem is to add something like this before you load your network:

```
let dummies []
create-turtles 2 [
  create-links-to other turtles
  set dummies fput self dummies
]
```

And then, *after* you have loaded your network:

```
foreach dummies [ t -> ask t [ die ] ]
```

This relies on the fact that NetLogo's unbreeded links can be either directed or undirected, but not both. By created dummy directed links before the network is loaded, we force NetLogo to create all other links as directed.

I have opened an issue on GitHub about the problem and will investigate further. Until then, that hack should save you.

Comment: Nicolas Payette, thank you so much, it worked. Thank you again.

Comment: What's the URL of the GitHub issue...?